# onClick function is not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I have on the left an image and on the right several icons. When someone clicks on the icon the image of the left side will change. 
In desktop works but not in mobile.

Here is my code, I hope you can help me

```
<div class="container container-amenidades-bloque2">
  <div class="col-sm-6 img-amenidades" id="div1">
     <img src="http://www.eqia.mx/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/amenidades.img-min.png"/>
  </div>

<div class="col-sm-6 container-all-icons-amenidades">
  <div class="container-icon-amenidades"  onclick="gym()" id="icon-gym">
    <img src="http://www.eqia.mx/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/iconohome-6.png">
    <p>Gym</p>
</div>

<div class="container-icon-amenidades" onclick="spa()" id="icon-spa">
  <img src="http://www.eqia.mx/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/iconohome-6.png">
  <p>Spa</p>
</div>

</div>   
</div>


<script>
    function divPic() {
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/MRT_Singapore_Destination_1.png'>";
    }

    function gym() {
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/10/MRT_Singapore_Destination_2.png'>";
    }

    function spa() {
        document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/MRT_Singapore_Destination_1.png'>";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You havent enclosed JavaScript code in document.ready function

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
           Your_code_here
     }
```

Hope this works

Comment: jQuery is not the solution to everything - especially not when it's a task that can be easily achieved with vanilla JavaScript. :p https://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif